# How do I publish my first articles?

Tags: publishing, food-writing

I am a freelance writer through Fiverr.com, but I am looking to get better gigs being that I cannot share my work outside of the website. I want to venture out writing for an article website in particular.

I am currently writing several articles and I have conducted interviews for them as well. Most are food & beverage restaurant and bar articles. Some are under the media category.

Once I finish these articles, how do I get them published so I can have a portfolio of relevant work under my belt to get hired for more legitimate article writing businesses?

Even if I have to pay for publishing, I'll do it as long as it makes me a relevant writer.

Answer (score 3):

If your question relates to **copyright** issues or Ts and Cs and re-publishing what you've already written: it's obviously a legal matter and *I'm not qualified to comment*. If you're allowed to link to them from elsewhere, the following may be helpful.

If you're after a platform to get noticed and improve your odds of getting better gigs I would recommend https://medium.com

You can tag your work, popularity is algorithmic, you may show up in people's streams or the Editor's top picks or email digests curated for you. Finally, you can put your bio with contact details or other work or personal website. Do explore that.

Example: (No idea who this is but he is coming up as 'popular' at the time of writing this answer). [https://medium.com/@*jacobward*](https://medium.com/@_jacobward_)

You can see his bio refers you to his Wordpress site where he owns his profile. You may be able to link to the end client directly from your bio on Medium.com or if you prefer to your own site where you can point to, allude or directly link to the entity for whom you've written.

Again, I cannot comment on the legalities of claiming ownership of an article that cannot leave a publication, as they presumably own the content. So best consult a lawyer, esp. if there are straight up copyright, NDA or anonymity policies with either your middleman entity or your current end-client.

Anyhow, I do hope this is somewhat helpful and wish you the very best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to get noticed from other sites or blogs where your contents are,
I recommend steemit.com or medium.com also though there may be lots more out there

Comment: Medium is already recommended in the other answer. Could you explain a bit more about Steemit, and why it would be a good option for the OP?

Comment: it's a platform where you publish your blog posts and earn crypto whenever you get an upvote, it has a post link where you can always refer people to view your blog posts.

Comment: check https://steemit.com/success/@ae1000/motivate-someone-around-you

Comment: Could you edit that information into your actual answer, please?